# Asp.net mvc 4 Large database using edmx is good?

Tags: asp.net, edmx

I am developing a web project in MVC 4 with a large database having 150 objects like tables, views, SPs. I want to know EDMX is good idea for accessing database regarding performance or optimization. If not than what should be used

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you may use `Entity Framework 5` without `EDMX`. Use any approach with EF5 - `Code-First` or `Database-First` and you should be good to go.

You will have a create a `context` to the database. It will save you from creating any `EDMX` file and other associated files.

Here is an MSDN link to [get started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907). Visit [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj590134) to choose the right approach. Another [link](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/model-first-database-first-or-code-first-ndash-update-to-data-points-column/) for EF v4.1.

> Please take this as a starting point.